# Select tag value doesn't restore to previous value after hit go back in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple select dropdown which contains 12 months of a year. If you click on one of then you will be redirected to a new page with data of the month you've selected.

In chrome, say I'm currently on January and I select February in the dropdown, then I will be redirected to February's page. Then I hit go back in chrome, it simply goes back to the previous page but the text of the select tab is still February. Meanwhile, if I inspect elements and I can see January is the one being select (which is correct).

I wonder is there a way to let the select tag restore to January after I hit go back?

Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that "Back" doesn't necessarily reload the previous page, rather, Chrome is restoring a snapshot of what it thinks it looked like. Every browser's history mechanism could be a little different. To really help you, you need to provide a [mcve]. Please [edit] something into your question that is reproducible and illustrates the issue.

Comment: @adeneo: the duplicate you provided shows how to *clear* fields upon going back, but this user is asking how to *set* a field. The answers in that question don't show an example of setting a field value. Do you still think this is a duplicate?

Comment: Looks like it was marked as a dupe, but if you just want to reset the one field, instead do this: `select.options[0].selected = true`.  Assuming `select` is your select element obtained by `var select = document.querySelector('select')` or similar.